# Query/Mutation in 2 service in @apollo/federation and @apollo/gateway

Tags: mysql, graphql, apollo, prisma

I Have a problem. I build 2 services graphql with 2 different tables but 2 tables have foreign keys and I want to query from service A( but must check the condition in service B). How I can query/mutation between 2 services. Thanks for your reply

Comment: Could you provide a little more context to your issue?

What libraries are you using, what version of Prisma are you running on, your models, and project configuration to replicate this and provide an response?

Comment: I change my question. I realize I can't auto query from service A to service B with the condition I want